# How do I make this list of lists into a list of tuples?

Tags: python, list, tuples

I'm having a bit of trouble with making this list of lists

`triangles= [[0, 30, 31], [2, 32, 38], [3, 24, 46], [4, 14, 27], [10, 18, 48], [12, 21, 35], [15, 39, 45], [17, 32, 38], [19, 32, 38], [21, 43, 44], [29, 43, 44]]`

into a list like this:

```
[(0,30),(30,31),(0,31),(2,32),(32,38),(2,38).. etc]
```

I have already tried this:

```
c_list=list(nx.clique.enumerate_all_cliques(G))
triangles=[x for x in c_list if len(x)==3]
for [u,v,w] in triangles:
    print((u,v),(v,w),(u,w))
```

since 'triangles' is a list of nodes that make triangles in a graph and I need the edges so that I can graph the triangles. However, I can't use this code because it doesn't have a type. So how do I turn it into a list of tuples?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
triangles = [[0, 30, 31], [2, 32, 38], [3, 24, 46], [4, 14, 27], [10, 18, 48], [12, 21, 35], [15, 39, 45], [17, 32, 38], [19, 32, 38], [21, 43, 44], [29, 43, 44]] 
y = list()
for i in triangles:
  y.append((i[0], i[1]))
  y.append((i[1], i[2]))
  y.append((i[0], i[2]))
print(y)
```

output: `[(0, 30), (30, 31), (0, 31), (2, 32), (32, 38), (2, 38), (3, 24), (24, 46), (3, 46), (4, 14), (14, 27), (4, 27), (10, 18), (18, 48), (10, 48), (12, 21), (21, 35), (12, 35), (15, 39), (39, 45), (15, 45), (17, 32), (32, 38), (17, 38), (19, 32), (32, 38), (19, 38), (21, 43), (43, 44), (21, 44), (29, 43), (43, 44), (29, 44)]`

Comment: May want to add in `y.append((i[1], i[2]))` as well since it looks like he wants all combinations of each triangle

Comment: @SyntaxVoid thanks for pointing I did miss that, its updated.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> c_list = [[0, 30, 31], [2, 32, 38], [3, 24, 46], [4, 14, 27], [10, 18, 48], [12, 21, 35], [15, 39, 45], [17, 32, 38], [19, 32, 38], [21, 43, 44], [29, 43, 44]]
>>> import itertools
>>> [t for L in c_list for t in itertools.combinations(L, 2)]
[(0, 30), (0, 31), (30, 31), (2, 32), (2, 38), (32, 38), (3, 24), (3, 46), (24, 46), (4, 14), (4, 27), (14, 27), (10, 18), (10, 48), (18, 48), (12, 21), (12, 35), (21, 35), (15, 39), (15, 45), (39, 45), (17, 32), (17, 38), (32, 38), (19, 32), (19, 38), (32, 38), (21, 43), (21, 44), (43, 44), (29, 43), (29, 44), (43, 44)]
```

The list comprehension is simple:

- first, take every list `L` of 3 elements (the triangle edges) in `c_list`;
- second, create combinations of edges for every `L` with `itertools.combinations`;
- third, pack the list with every combination.

Answer (score 0):

```
triangles =  [[0, 30, 31], [2, 32, 38], [3, 24, 46], [4, 14, 27], [10, 18, 48], [12,21, 35], [15, 39, 45], [17, 32, 38], [19, 32, 38], [21, 43, 44], [29, 43, 44]]
edge = []
for points in triangles:
    edge.append(tuple(points[0:2]))
    edge.append(tuple(points[1:3]))
    edge.append(tuple(points[:3:2]))
print(edge)
```

Yeils output:

```
[(0, 30), (30, 31), (0, 31), (2, 32), (32, 38), (2, 38), (3, 24), (24, 46), (3, 46), (4, 14), (14, 27), (4, 27), (10, 18), (18, 48), (10, 48), (12, 21), (21, 35), (12, 35), (15, 39), (39, 45), (15, 45), (17, 32), (32, 38), (17, 38), (19, 32), (32, 38), (19, 38), (21, 43), (43, 44), (21, 44), (29, 43), (43, 44), (29, 44)]
```

Answer (score 0):

With a small change you to your code you can have the list of tuples:

```
triangles= [[0, 30, 31], [2, 32, 38], [3, 24, 46], [4, 14, 27], [10, 18, 48], [12, 21, 35], [15, 39, 45], [17, 32, 38], [19, 32, 38], [21, 43, 44], [29, 43, 44]]

for [u,v,w] in triangles:
    element = [(u,v),(v,w),(u,w)]
    print(type(element))
    for item in element:
        print(type(item))
```

output will be like:

```
<class 'list'>
<class 'tuple'>
<class 'tuple'>
<class 'tuple'>
<class 'list'>
<class 'tuple'>
<class 'tuple'>
<class 'tuple'>
...
```